# Load rtf or text file into UITextView iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios4

Hi i was wondering how should i load rtf or text file into UITextView i use several codes but did't work ,

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"txt"];
myTextView.text = filePath;
```

thank you .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may try with this:

```
NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
myTextView.text  = myText;
```

Comment: Wait, what is your textView, what is yourText, it seems that your variable name has problems. Can you print out the NSString after getting from `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile...]`. I want to see the results there

Comment: myText is      'UITextView' and 'myTextView' is just a name, my file is a txt file with UTF8 Encoding .

Comment: did you do the NSLog() to see what's going on after you get the content, any content there? Did you try to put an NSError as a third variable like David said

Comment: yes , but the compiler shows me a warning: passing argument 1 of 'NSLog' from incompatible pointer type.

Comment: IAM SO SORRY I FORGOT TO CONNECT THE OUTLET WITH ON INTERFACE BUILDER SOOOOOO SORRY

Comment: @vodkhang,is it possible attributedString for that string?

Comment: All this does is convert the RTF into raw text. I tried this with an RTFD and it wouldn't even load. Then, I switched to an RTF and it showed raw RTF text instead of formatting it in a RichText way. So, I submitted another answer below on how I got it working.

Answer (score 9):

```
myTextView.attributedText =
[   NSAttributedString.alloc
    initWithFileURL:[ NSBundle.mainBundle URLForResource:@"filename" withExtension:@"rtf"  ]
    options:nil
    documentAttributes:nil
    error:nullptr
];
```

Comment: Slightly strange formatting, but it works for loading a rich text file and setting the `attributedText` property of a `UITextView`.

Comment: This does work but as an example it promotes bad practices. Using dot syntax to call `alloc` is confusing at best, and a misuse of dot syntax at worst. Not following standard multiline parameter alignment conventions makes it hard to read.

Comment: Is it worth to decrease my reputation? You dogmatist.

Answer (score 8):

What you've done so far will get you the name of the file, you need to go one step further and actually read the contents of the file into an NSString, using something like:

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath 
                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                           error:&err];
if (fileContents == nil) {
    NSLog("Error reading %@: %@", filePath, err);
} else {
    myTextView.text = fileContents;
}
```

That will work for plain text (assuming your file is in UTF8 encoding); you'll have to do something a lot fancier for RTF (UITextView doesn't know how to display RTF).

Comment: If it's not working, maybe you should check the error status (instead of ignoring it by passing `nil`).

Answer (score 0):

1. Drag your TextView control (I had to click 3 times until it said NSTextView) to your AppDelegate.m file underneath the first `@interface` line. Mine was `@interface AppDelegate ()`. The reason for the three clicks is because by default when you drag a TextView control on a window, it creates 3 controls and it's only the inner, inner one that is set to NSTextView. The other controls deal with scrolling and screen clipping. Then, choose to create an outlet and name it something like `txtRich` or whatever you want. This created this entry for me in my case:

```
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSTextView *txtRich;
```

2. Find a class method where you want to load the RTFD. I did mine in the AppDelegate.m under `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. Inside that, paste something like this:

```
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *sFile= [myBundle pathForResource:@"myrichfile" ofType:@"rtfd"];
[self.txtRich readRTFDFromFile:sFile];
```

You may be wondering where this `mainBundle` comes from, and if you have to declare it somewhere. The answer is no. It's freaking magic, created by default, just like the NSNotificationCenter `defaultCenter` variable. It refers to your own application bundle.

3. Now, use TextEdit to create a file myrichfile.rtfd. Save it in your project folder. Drag it to your project window under the Supporting Files. When you get prompted, go with the defaults. This bundles it with your project in a Resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to load a rtf file

```
NSURL * url = [NSBundle.mainBundle URLForResource:@"example"
                                    withExtension:@"rtf"];
NSData * content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError * e;
NSAttributedString * aText = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                              initWithData:content
                              options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType}
                              documentAttributes:NULL
                              error:&e];

self.textView.attributedText = aText;
```