# iphone parse RTF file format programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, rtf, rich-text-editor

I want to edit a text file (basically a rich text editing) like making some text bold, changing font, color etc. I have found many rich text editor programs. But i need to parse a .rtf file and and show the contents, make it possible to edit and save it back to the .rtf file.

**So I am not getting any idea to read and write into a .rtf file.**

Answer (score 0):

I got a library for RTF Reader and RTF Writer.

https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/iOS-4.x

Initially you may get many errors on building the library.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I think you can add your .rtf file to a `UITextView` and once in the `UITextView` you can  make some text bold, changing font, color etc.

```
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
myTextView.text  = myText;
```

OR

```
 NSError *err = nil;
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath 
                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                           error:&err];
if (fileContents == nil) {
    NSLog("Error reading %@: %@", filePath, err);
} else {
    myTextView.text = fileContents;
}
```

Also please check the following link

[Read/Write RTF File](http://iphonedevelopersunited.blogspot.in/2011/05/readwrite-txt-file-in-iphone-sdk.html)

Refer the answer from [Load rtf or text file into UITextView iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865330/load-rtf-or-text-file-into-uitextview-iphone-sdk)

Comment: This will work in plain text. For rtf formatted file,It will be a rtf formatted string, not a text.(UITextView doesn't know how to display RTF).